# Comparing articles in two databases and only delete on the following condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table, call it "t1", and another table call it "t2"

I want to INSERT something into t1 if it is NOT in t2. The condition to know if it's already in t2 (AKA its a DUPLICATE) is if the text from one of the fields in one entry in t2 already exists (matches exactly with that to be inserted

How, do I formulate this condition using SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

You want to

*If an item is "already" in t2, but NOT in t1 then I would like to avoid executing an INSERT statement.*

So insert should take place on negation of above statement i.e.

*item should not be in t2 and item should be present in t1*

```
insert into target_table( column list )
select ( column list)
from source_table
where item not in (select item from t2)
and item in (select item from t1)
```

*what I meant was that if the article is NOT in t2, THEN I want to insert it into t1. Its pretty simple really*

```
   insert into t1 ( <column list>)
   select <column list>
   from source_table
   where item not in (select item from t2)
```

You can use

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE item like '%'+@itemvalue+'%')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO t1
        VALUES (@itemvalue)
    END
```

Comment: i probably was confused: what I meant was that if the article is NOT in t2, THEN I want to insert it into t1. But if it is in t2, then I DON't want to INSERT. Its pretty simple really. the condition to know if its there is if text in one field matches exactly

Comment: @Timtam plz check now

Comment: ok thanks is source_table the same as t2? and don't you mean insert into t1?

Comment: @Timtam .. no it can be...are you getting item to be inserted in a variable..if yes then check edited answer above..

Comment: i want to insert into t1 if it is NOT in t2, i don't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SELECT from VALUES and join with t2, for example, to insert multiple rows at the same time (of course you could insert only one)

```
insert into t1 ( id, label)
select id, label
from (VALUES(1, 'item1'),
            (3, 'item3'),
            (5, 'item5')) as T(id,label)
where not exists(select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t.id)
```

This FROM VALUES syntax is available in Sql2008, for previous versions, you have replace 
`VALUES(...)` clause 
with

```
SELECT 1,'idem1' 
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'item2'
```

If you have your data in variables, you can simply do (NO FROM):

```
insert t1 ( id, label)
select @id, @label
where not exists(select 1 from t2 where t2.id = @id)
```